# Inserting a userform value to the active row in a specific column

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am currently doing a project in work around training. Specifically we are checking the quality of work for a group of trainees and are inserting the work to an excel document. Each new record is called a "check"

I have created a Userform which allows users to select dropdowns regarding; the trainee name, the type of work carried out and whether the outcome is correct. In addition they are able to add specific notes as feedback through a text box. This part is working exactly as intended.

However, a staff member advised that she wanted to alter the note that she had entered to the system.

At the moment, the VBA code to insert a new check unprotects the work sheet and inserts the data input by the user to the Userform to the next available blank row (blank in column A only), before protecting it again with the same password.

In practice, this means that users can only add new records and not amend the current ones.

I would like to allow the user to select a cell, before clicking the "edit note" button to open the Macro. This will open a small `Userform` where the person can add a new note. By selecting a cell, I am hoping to take the current row of that cell and input the new data into the current row, `column F`.

At the moment I have created this new `userform` and have the enter button and cancel button working as intended.

THE ISSUE

The issue I have is that I'm self-taught in VBA and I am having difficulty creating a code which inserts code from the selected row into `column F`.

I have tried to use `"Active Cell"` but this is returning errors. I have tried `Active Row` but in all honesty I have no idea what I'm doing being self-taught. The code used on the previous `userform` is a mixture of things I've picked up and code altered from tutorial websites.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

''''cmdAdd is the name of the confirmation box to enter the users new notes)

If Notesbox.Text = "" Then
   messagebox.Show ("You must select a item")
   Exit Sub
Else
 'Process your Code
End If
```

''''the above text is to prevent the user completing the form without including any values)

```
Sheets("Checks").Unprotect Password:="PASSWORD"


''' The below code is to copy input values to sheet.
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Checks")
lRow = ActiveCell
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
End With
'Clear input controls.

''' The below code is to clear the userform, save the workbook then close the userform. The password protection is then readded to prevent the user from altering the workbook out-with the userform. 


Me.Notesbox.Value = ""

ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Close UserForm.
Unload Me

Sheets("Checks").Protect Password:="PASSWORD"



End Sub
```

Error message:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

This takes me to the line of code:

```
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
```

Comment: `lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(Xlup).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveCell` returns a range object, from which you can get the row and column by simply using `ActiveCell.Row`.

See if the below helps:

```vb
Sub ActiveCellRow()

Dim rngActCell As Range
Set rngActCell = ActiveCell 'ActiveCell is a range

Dim rowActCell As Long
rowActCell = rngActCell.Row

Dim colActCell As Long
colActCell = rngActCell.Column

Debug.Print rngActCell.Address
Debug.Print rowActCell
Debug.Print colActCell

'So in your case:
With ws
    .Cells(rowActCell, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
End With

'Or without declaring all that
With ws
    .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** to be more clear, replace in your code these lines:

```vb
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
End With
```

**with**

```vb
With ws
    .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @FAB. When I use your code though it disables the functionality of the click button cmdAdd.

When I use "Run sub/Userform" it appears to enter the text into the next available empty row instead of the currently selected row.

Comment: @AlistairMacIntyre you need to select from the above only what you need for your code to work, i.e.: replace `.Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value` with `.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value = Me.Notesbox.Value`. In my answer I've just included additional ways of dealing with the `ActiveCell` range.

Comment: absolutely excellent. It's working as intended now. As I say I'm just self-teaching myself in it for a few work projects so I'd say I was a complete beginner at the moment. 

I appreciate your time and have marked your answer as correct. Thanks again!